# How to convert json into array in Jquery

Tags: jquery, json

**Script**

```
var data = '{"Err0":"Only letters and white space allowed in Name"}';
try {
                  //convert to json string
                      arr = $.parseJSON(data); //convert to javascript array
                      arr.each(function(key,value){
                       console.log(value);
                  });
              } catch (e) {
                  $("#id").val(data);
              }
```

Trying to get the value of the json but its throwing error

Any help

Thanks

Comment: `$data != data` .. That error shouldn't have been a pretty simple clue

Comment: @charlietfl updated my question

Comment: @Andreas it was a typo I fixed it

Comment: `$.parseJSON()` returns an object (and not a jQuery object) which has no `.each()` method

Answer (score 9, accepted):

use below code

insteade of `arr.each` use `$.each(arr,`.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Lwj55a58/)

```
var data= '{"Err0":"Only letters and white space allowed in Name"}';
arr = $.parseJSON(data); //convert to javascript array
$.each(arr,function(key,value){
    alert(value);
});
```

Comment: @charlietfl that was a typo that I updated in my question , My actual mistake was `arr.each()` thanks anyways

Comment: @charlietfl check my answer again its not only typo . use of $.each function also wrong